# I am having some troubles with my code - it keeps reprinting out the avgs

Tags: java, for-loop

I am writing a code that will output the row size and column size of the matrix.
n
Then output the row averages and lastly the column averages. However, the columns avg just keeps on printing out.

```
/*
 * Programmer: Olawale Onafowokan
 * Date: February 6, 2014
 * Purpose: Prints the row and column averages
 */
class dfsahfa
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    int [][] scores = {{ 20, 18, 23, 20, 16 },
      { 30, 20, 18, 21, 20 },
      { 16, 19, 16, 53, 24 },
      { 25, 24, 22, 24, 25 }};
    outputArray(scores);
  }

  public static void outputArray(int[][] array)
  { int sum= 0;
    double average=0.00;

    int rowSize = array.length;
    int columnSize = array[0].length;
    int[] colSum =new int[array[0].length];
    int[] Colavg=new int[array[0].length]; ///
    System.out.println("rows="+rowSize+ "cols=" +columnSize); 

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){   
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){                
        sum = sum + array[i][j];
        colSum[j]+= array[i][j];
        Colavg[j]=colSum[j]/4;
         average=sum/(double)array.length; 

    }

    System.out.println("Print the  averages of the row =" +  average);
}  
for(int k=0;k<colSum.length;k++)
  for(int h=0;h<Colavg.length;h++){


    System.out.println("Print the sum of columns of avg =" + Colavg[h]); }


} 


     }
```

Output:

run dfsahfa
rows=4cols=5

```
Print the  averages of the row =24.25
Print the  averages of the row =51.5
Print the  averages of the row =83.5
Print the  averages of the row =113.5
Print the sum of columns of avg =22
Print the sum of columns of avg =20
Print the sum of columns of avg =19
Print the sum of columns of avg =29
Print the sum of columns of avg =21
Print the sum of columns of avg =22
Print the sum of columns of avg =20
Print the sum of columns of avg =19
Print the sum of columns of avg =29
Print the sum of columns of avg =21
Print the sum of columns of avg =22
Print the sum of columns of avg =20
Print the sum of columns of avg =19
Print the sum of columns of avg =29
Print the sum of columns of avg =21
Print the sum of columns of avg =22
Print the sum of columns of avg =20
Print the sum of columns of avg =19
Print the sum of columns of avg =29
```

Is there an easy why to fix this? And why is it doing it?

Comment: You missed a `}`. I'll leave where it should be up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first double for loop, you are printing out the row averages as well as computing the column averages and storing them in the array called Colavg.  In the next for loop, you just want to print the column averages that you have stored in your array.  You just need a single for loop to print these values.  So eliminate the line that reads

```
for(int k=0;k<colSum.length;k++)
```

And simply loop through Colavg to print each of these values once.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){   
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){                
        sum = sum + array[i][j];
        colSum[j]+= array[i][j];
        Colavg[j]=colSum[j]/4;
        average=sum/(double)array.length; 
    }

    System.out.println("Print the  averages of the row =" +  average);
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){   
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){                
        sum = sum + array[i][j];
        colSum[j]+= array[i][j];
        Colavg[j]=colSum[j]/4;
         average=sum/(double)array.length; 

    }
}
System.out.println("Print the  averages of the row =" +  average);
```